# Transparent proxy for wired+wireless network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, proxy

I want to install squid as a transparent proxy for my home network.

I have a HP microserver currently serving as my NAS+media server. I am thinking if I get a second NIC for the server I can lay the network out as follows:

```
[internet] <---> [modem+router] <---> [microserver] <---> [rest of network]
```

With this layout I can then install dhcp, DNS, squid and anything else I would like to have between me and the internet.

Now on to the problem: The modem+router device is also responsible for the wifi portion of my network. I would really like to have the wifi network also go through the proxy. Is there any way of doing this without getting a separate modem or wifi access point?

[This](ftp://ftp.d-link.co.za/d-linkftp/pdfs/products/DSL-2750U/DSL-2750U_ds.pdf) is the adsl router that I have, it was supplied by my ISP.

The first prize answer will be where I can simply remove the microserver from the picture without needing to reconfigure settings on the router and/or client devices.

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole point in having a transparent proxy is that it's transparent to the clients, and as such you should configure your clients to use the proxy [microserver] as its gateway, so you would need to configure DHCP to use the IP of [microserver] as your private LAN's gateway.

Then configure IP forwarding on [microserver] so it forwards internet traffic to your [modem+router].

"The first prize answer will be where I can simply remove the microserver from the picture without needing to reconfigure settings on the router and/or client devices."

Do you mean, configuring it such that if the microserver went down, you wouldn't need to reconfigure anything on the clients/router to make it all work again?

Comment: I did not think about setting up dhcp on router in addition to setting it up on the server. You understand my last question correctly. If the microserver goes down I can simply change the default gateway for the router's dhcp settings and all will be well   sans a proxy.